# Why can't I catch ElementClickInterceptedException exception in Selenide, but can catch it with Throwable?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, junit, selenide

I have a section of code that looks like this in my Java + Selenide + JUnit project:

```
        for (int retries = 3; !menuItem.is(visible); --retries) {
            if (retries < 1) {
                fail("Button does not appear");
            }
            try {
                burgerMenu.click();
            } catch (ElementClickInterceptedException ex) {
                System.err.println("\nCaught!\n");
                break;
            }
            Selenide.sleep(1000);
        }
        
        menuItem.click();
```

The logic is intending to click a sub-menu item by clicking on the menu creating button until it appears. It's done this way as the menu UI is a bit finnicky, but that's besides the point.

**The curiosity is why the catch() is never called, even when the line burgerMenu.click() generates a ElementClickInterceptedException.**

This debugger confirms it's this line generating the exception, and that the exception is ElementClickInterceptedException. The same occurs when changing the catch to be for Exception or RuntimeException, the catch block is not entered and instead the program terminates. However, if I change the catch() to Throwable, then the catch block is entered. How is this happening, why can't I catch the ElementClickInterceptException, and why does catching Throwable work instead?

Stacktrace:

```
Invalid element state [By.xpath: //div[normalize-space()='Redacted']]: element click intercepted: Element <div class="redacted">...</div> is not clickable at point (800, 400). Other element would receive the click: <div class="redacted2">...</div>
Screenshot: file:/C:/Users/me/myproject/build/reports/tests/1696003443588.0.png
Page source: file:/C:/Users/me/myproject/build/reports/tests/1696003443588.0.html
Timeout: 45 s.
Caused by: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div class="redacted">...</div> is not clickable at point (800, 200). Other element would receive the click: <div class="redacted2">...</div>
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ExceptionWrapper.wrap(ExceptionWrapper.java:26)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:153)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:83)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.redacted.myTest(redactedName.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div class="redacted">...</div> is not clickable at point (800, 400). Other element would receive the click: <div class="redacted2">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.92)
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [a97g530216ey2d2bc87f719b864df3e1, clickElement {id=4B8D5586D36470988AB7D64CF6F299F4_element_96}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 117.0.5938.92, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 117.0.5938.92 (67649b10b92b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\me\AppData\Lo...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: // redacted 
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (a97g530216ey2d2bc87f719b864df3e1)] -> xpath: //div[normalize-space()='Redacted']]
Session ID: a97g530216ey2d2bc87f719b864df3e1
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Click.defaultClick(Click.java:97)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Click.click(Click.java:54)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Click.execute(Click.java:31)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Click.execute(Click.java:21)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Commands.execute(Commands.java:159)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:131)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: What you posted is only the latter part of the stacktrace. "Caused by: ElementClickInterceptedException" <- This refers to a missing part of the Stacktrace that you didn't post which would show you where the problem starts and if for example the ElementClickInterceptedException is wrapped in another exception and not caught because of that.

Comment: For example `throw new IllegalArgumentException(new RuntimeException())` will produce a stacktrace saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.  As you can see the "caused by" refers to the wrapped Exception and not the one that is actually being thrown.

Comment: Hi @OHGODSPIDERS, I've added the rest of the stacktrace as it appears in IntelliJ. It didn't appear to contain anything useful, just build + environment info.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The part that is missing is **before** "caused by" not after that. Either you or your IDE / server is cutting of the first part of the stacktrace that contains the information what exception is actually being thrown. The "caused by" is only the latter half! PS: if you say that catching Throwable works why don't you use that and print the class of the cought throwable to see what kind of exception it actually is? Not that i think this "trick" is necessary as the full stacktrace should contain that information.

Comment: But in the end your problem is really that simply that if your `catch (ElementClickInterceptedException ex)` isn't being entered then that is not the exception that is being thrown in this kind of code. Your stacktrace shows that what is being thrown is some Exception that had a `ElementClickInterceptedException` passed as a argument for `cause`. What class that exception actually is is not answerable by me as already mentioned you left out the part of the stacktrace that contains this information.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS My bad, I didn't realize the above statement was the exception, I thought it was a message about the below exception, it's above some screenshot links in the output. I've updated stacktrace again with the above added.

 The class is com.codeborne.selenide.ex.InvalidStateException, it's great-great-great-grandparent is Error. That (at least to me) is very surprising behaviour from selenide! I'd expect to be able to recover from button not being clickable. https://selenide.org/javadoc/current/com/codeborne/selenide/ex/InvalidStateException.html

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS This com.codeborne.selenide.ex.InvalidStateException class isn't mentioned in the output, just the error message from it. It's very surprising to me that Selenide would use something inherited from Error for something that's very recoverable and not out of the ordinary for UI testing. But I understand now what is happening. Thanks for your help.